# Deep Q problem. Some q-Values are always greater

Tags: deep-learning, deep-rl, dqn

### Description

My problem is to make actor play on stock market. I am trying to teach him playing on some portion of data. I interpolated data to uniformed interals and normalized or standarized all features the way I though is correct. Most of them are <0,1>

I have few neural networks, using different architectures.
But they face same problems. They seems not to learn.

### Model

In input I pass

- data input (2d time series data)
- actor state (1 or 0)

  currently it is just 0 or 1, depending if actor has any asset

I predict 3 actions q-values.

- 1. Buy
- 2. Pass
- 3. Sell

Example model:

[image: Example neural network picture]

### Parameters

I used $1e-5$ learning rate and batch of 2000.

Discount: I used $0.98$ before, but picture below is $discount=0.1$

### Using bellman equation for deep LR

$Q(a,s) $ ← $reward + \gamma * max(Q(s'))$

```
    new_vector = rewards + discount * max_future_argq * (1 - dones.astype(int))
    for i, (ac, v) in enumerate(zip(actions, new_vector)):
        curr_qvals[i, ac] = v
```

##### Training with new qvals

`envs_states_arr` - env array of shape `(actors, timewindow, features)`

`states` - actor states of shape `(actors, 1`)

```
history_ob = mod.fit([envs_states_arr, states], new_qvals, shuffle=True,
                             batch_size=mini_batchsize,
                             verbose=False)
```

### Reward function

`discrete_stock` is hidden integer for given actor, it means amount of items actor has

`price` - normalized price in given state.

`BASE_PENALTY` $ = -1$

`INVALID_MOVE` $ = -10$

`False` and `True` are indicating valid moves just for me.

```
if action == 0:
    "BUY"
    if discrete_stock == 0:
        return -price, True
    else:
        return INVALID_MOVE, False

elif action == 1:
    "PASS"
    return 3 * BASE_PENALTY, True

elif action == 2:
    "SELL"
    if discrete_stock <= 0:
        return INVALID_MOVE, False

    return price * 2, True
```

### More about problem

I think it is already small learning rate. Should I go even lower learning rate and bigger batch size?

I am confused about this problem. You can see there are some `-10` rewards in plot, so some outputs had invalid move, yet I don't see model to set any actions in that direction.

[image: Training results]

## Is model learning?

Loss is going very low. So is my solution designed wrong?

Comment: Thanks for editing. You show some code, but it is hard to interpret - and also it leaves the question of whether you have the wrong idea, or simply implemented it wrong. Instead,please explain the "game" the agent is playing, what the rules are etc.

Comment: I am however, concerned by your "hidden" variable which has large influence on expected reward. I can see that could be a major problem. Is it truly hidden from the agent? Does it change when agent buys/sells (and not change on pass) or is is set randomly on each time step?

Comment: Yes and no. Amount is hidden, but actor knows if it has any asset, so it sees state as 1 or 0. Also rules are simple. It can buy only 1 at the time, and gets reward relative to price.

Comment: Initially I trained him like any other "Game" but now I removed end condition and do not use "done" samples, cause there is no really end to the game, it was end of  the session.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147353/discussion-between-grzegorz-krug-and-neil-slater).

Comment: @NeilSlater thanks again for help, I found the issue, I copied values from actions to rewards.... just code issue

Comment: That makes sense, I couldn't identify a major mistake in your work in our chat. But I hope the talk around what you are doing was still useful

Comment: It was! I should visit this stack more often